# Displaying a (Play! 2) form input field if value is not empty

Tags: jquery, playframework

I have an input in my form that I only want to display if the value is not null or empty, so I create the input in code (the Play! generated html looks like this) -

```
<dl class=" " id="entry_field">
  <dt><label for="entry">Blah:</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="entry" name="entry" value="Blah" readonly="readonly">
  </dd>
</dl>
```

and then hide it in the jQuery onload event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#entry_field" ).hide();
});
```

So now I want to test whether the input entry has a non null value and if it does, display the whole thing.  So I tried the following, but the entry_field does not display.

```
if( $('#entry').attr("value") != '') {
  $( '#entry_field').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are adding this inside the **DOM** Ready handler..

Make sure you add it inside it otherwise it may not work..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#entry_field").hide();

    if ($('#entry').attr("value") != '') {
        $('#entry_field').show();
    }
});​
```

Use `.val()`  instead

```
 if( $('#entry').val() !== '') {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zfnSs/1/)**

Comment: Golly that was quick!  It still doesn't display though.  Should my code be in the onready event or should I move it into another function, in which case how would I call it (i.e. would I need some sort of onload type of event)?

Comment: If you enclose you code inside document.ready function you would not be needing the onload event

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your 2nd slice of code is being called?
Could you try, maybe, adding a console.log("hey") or something? 'Cause I made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RedKnight91/rv7Zp/) to try the code and it totally works : )

Try adding both of the fields in the $(document).ready, like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#entry_field" ).hide();

    if( $('#entry').attr("value") != '') {
        $( '#entry_field').show();
    }
});
```

if you want to check on load, if you want to call the function when you trigger an event or something, be sure to assign it to the right event.